# intel icpc compiler errors with boost on ubuntu

Tags: boost, compiler-errors, icc

I'm trying to get Boost working with Intel's compiler icpc on Ubuntu. My admin installed the package from [this webpage](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libboost-all-dev). I'm trying now to run a [basic example from the Boost's webpage](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library), compiling as follows:

```
icpc -I /usr/include/boost example.cpp -L/usr/lib/ -lboost_regex,
```

and I get a bunch of compiler errors of this form:

```
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp(233): error: copy constructor for class "boost::detail::shared_count" may not have a parameter of type "boost::detail::shared_count"
  shared_count(shared_count && r): pi_(r.pi_) // nothrow
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp(233): error: expected a ")"
  shared_count(shared_count && r): pi_(r.pi_) // nothrow
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp(233): error: identifier "r" is undefined
  shared_count(shared_count && r): pi_(r.pi_) // nothrow
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp(340): error: copy constructor for class "boost::detail::weak_count" may not have a parameter of type "boost::detail::weak_count"
  weak_count(weak_count && r): pi_(r.pi_) // nothrow
```

etc. Surprisingly (or not), this thing's working OK with g++, simply writing:

```
g++ example.cpp -o example.out -lboost_regex
```

I'd be really grateful if you could help me with this. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted points to `boost 1.40`, while the issue you encountered seems [to be fixed since 1.47](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5878). (Note that the [current boost version is 1.53](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_53_0.html).)